# Updating data from remote object by jQuery/Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a beginner with jQuery. My project is MVC3 by asp.net. I have a remote object named Recorder.

```
class Recorder{ public double Value { get; set; }}
```

I want to update the main page each second to update recorder value on page load. How can I write the jQuery code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript `setInterval` function to execute a function at a specified interval.  For example

```
<script>
  var timer = setInterval(getRecorder, 1000);

  function getRecorder() {
    // Call a method on the server that returns JSON
    $.get('MyController/MyAction', function(data) {
      // update the DOM based on returned data
    });
  }
</script>
```

Note, the timer can be cancelled using `clearTimeout(timer);`

Answer (score 0):

Polling the server every second is an extremely expensive operation. Consider using signalR for this, perf tested at some pretty high benchmarks. It retains an efficient open connection to clients to stream data when there is data to stream, and it will fall back to supported technologies if say for ex. We sockets isn't supported, it could fall back to long polling.